# How i can show tracing of how my .net 8.0 console application which uses PnP core SDK interact with sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, console-application, .net-8.0, pnp-core-sdk

I have this .NET 8.0 console application, which uses PnP core SDK to connect to SharePoint online:-

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using PnP.Core.Auth;
using PnP.Core.Model.SharePoint;
using PnP.Core.QueryModel;
using PnP.Core.Services;
using PnP.Core.Services.Builder.Configuration;
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

namespace ConsoleApp4
{
internal class Program
{
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
var tenantId = "";
var clientId = "*****************8";
var certificatePath = @"c:\CERT****.pfx";
var certificatePassword = "********************";

        // Initialize a new service collection
        var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();

        // Load the certificate
        var certificate = new X509Certificate2(certificatePath, certificatePassword, X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

        // Configure logging
        //serviceCollection.AddLogging(builder =>
        //{
        //    builder.AddConsole();
        //});

        // Add and configure PnP Core SDK
        serviceCollection.AddPnPCore(options =>
        {
            options.PnPContext.GraphFirst = false; // Set true if you prefer to use Graph over CSOM when possible
           // options.HttpRequests.UserAgent = "ISV|Contoso|ProductX";
            options.Sites.Add("SiteToWorkWith", new PnPCoreSiteOptions
            {
                SiteUrl = "https://****.sharepoint.com/sites/****",
                AuthenticationProvider = new X509CertificateAuthenticationProvider(clientId, tenantId, certificate)
            });
        });

        // Build the service provider
        var serviceProvider = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();

        // Use the service provider to get the IPnPContextFactory instance
        var pnpContextFactory = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IPnPContextFactory>();

        // Now you can use the IPnPContextFactory to get a PnPContext and perform operations
        var context = await pnpContextFactory.CreateAsync("SiteToWorkWith");
        // Assume the fields where not yet loaded, so loading them with the list
        var myList = await context.Web.Lists.GetByTitleAsync("Work Orders", p => p.Title,
                                                             p => p.Fields.QueryProperties(p => p.InternalName,
                                                                                           p => p.FieldTypeKind,
                                                                                           p => p.TypeAsString,
                                                                                           p => p.Title));
        int i = 0;
        var t = "";
        // Do a paged retrieval of the list items
        await foreach (var listItem in myList.Items)
        {
            // Do something with the list item
            t= listItem["Created"].ToString();
            i++;
        }

        

        // Example operation: Print the title of the SharePoint site
        // Explicitly load the Title property of the Web
        await context.Web.LoadAsync(w => w.Title);

        Console.WriteLine($"Site title: {context.Web.Title}"+ i);

        // Ensure to dispose the context
        context.Dispose();
    }
}
}
```

but is there a way to show/trace the requests that get executed from my console application? so i can track how the console application interact with SharePoint behind the senses? so i can optimized it as needed?

Thanks

Comment: I think https://github.com/pnp/pnpcore/discussions might be a better place to ask that question :)

Comment: @leberknecht i thought i can get a help, as there is already a Tag for Pnp-core-sdk

Comment: not saying its wrong to ask here :) if the framework doesnt offer that capability, you could use wireshark or some other sniffer. From what i know, wireshark can be configured to sniff on TLS traffic given you have the certs of the client.